# Can't install php 8.0 bcmath

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-18.04, bcmath

I need to install the bcmath module because it is necessary for the wordpress ip2location plugin but I'm finding it impossible. I have followed other similar posts and nothing has worked. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) and php 8.0.28.

I have tried:

```
apt update
apt install php-bcmath
Error:
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php-bcmath : Depends: php7.2-bcmath but it is not going to be installed
-------------------------------------------------------
apt install php8.0-bcmath
Error:
E: Unable to locate package php8.0-bcmath
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php8.0-bcmath'
```

E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php8.0-bcmath'

Have also tried changing the repositories, adding ondrej for example, same error.

Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please keep in mind that PHP 8.0 is out of support. You should use any supported version. Also, Ondrej's repository has stopped supporting Ubuntu 18.04 last year, see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1922 - as 18.04 is also no longer under standard support

Answer (score 0):

According to TecAdmin:

> Ubuntu 18.04 comes with PHP 7.2 installed by default.

And while you are trying to install PHP 8.0 related package, you can do this by adding a PPA - Personal Package Archives - to Ubuntu, Or, by compiling PHP from source, Your available solutions are to:

1. Compile PHP from source with `--enable-bcmath`
2. Add `ondrej/php` PPA - Personal Package Archives -.

```
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
apt update
apt install php8.0-bcmath
```

3. Compile the extension itself from source as a shared extension